# Subset dataframe based on level of a factor

Tags: r, dataframe

I have dataframe `df1`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(respondent = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)),
                 location = factor(c("California", "Oregon", "Oregon",
                                     "Texas", "Oregon", "Mexico", "Canada")))
```

I want to subset it so that only rows with level `Oregon` of factor `location` remain in the dataframe:

```
df2 <- data.frame(respondent = factor(c(2, 3, 5)),
                 location = factor(c("Oregon", "Oregon",
                                     "Oregon")))
```

What's the most straightforward way to subset a dataframe based on a level of a dataframe?

Comment: `df2 <- subset(df1, location == "Oregon")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `subset` and wrap with `droplevels` to drop the unused `levels` as it is a `factor` column

```
df2 <- droplevels(subset(df1, location == 'Oregon'))
```